# Нельзя кликнуть на клонированный <input type="file">?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-form, jquery-file-upload

Делаю мультизагрузку, этот скрипт должен клонировать, а после кликать на *input*, для загрузки нового фото. Вот только он или кликает на *input*, или только клонирует.

```
$(document).on('click', '#clonner', function() {
    $(document).find('.img-copy').first().clone(true, true).appendTo('.img-copy-append-here .row');
    $('.img-copy').last().find('input[type="file"]').click();
});
```

Этот вариант только нажмет на последний *input*, закомментировав клик ивент, клонирование работает.

**Блок для клонирования:**

```
...
    <div style="display: none;">
    <div class="col-md-3 img-copy">
        <img src="http://lara53/imgs/no_image.png"  >
        <input type="file" name="gallery[]" style="display: none;">
    </div>
</div>
    <form action="/product/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
```

Comment: Вам нужно динамическое добавление полей в форму? Я правильно понял?

Comment: У вас вполне рабочий вариант. Я нажимаю - всё нормально клонирует и загружает